# find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes

Tags: shell, unix

I write a shell script. I have a problem.
I run my script and have an error
My error as below,

```
find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).
That means that '-name 'computer/'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.
You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  
Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `computer/''.
/behome/computer/.mozilla
/behome/computer/.mozilla/extensions
/behome/computer/.mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
...
```

Comment: I see a warning, but no error… Are you missing results that you expected?  Getting results that you didn't expect?  Given that none of the output that you've shown includes `folder1` or `folder2`, I don't think you're actually running `./scriptname -d folder1 folder2`, either. What is this script _supposed_ to do?

Comment: Also, the use of `find` like: `find $dir1 -printf "%f\n"` is looking for files _in_ the directory `$dir1`;  it's not looking _for_ directories named `$dir1`.  Is this what you're intending to do?

Comment: The problem is that you're passing an entire path to the `-name` parameter of `find`. What exactly do you want this script to do? If you are just looking to find if the file is in the second directory, then you would set `find` to be: `find $dir2 -name "${i##*/}" -print`

Comment: Are these just one level (flat) directories, or entire tree structures? If flat, then you don't need `find`. On a separate note, your `if [[ -d "${folder1}" "${folder2}" ]]` looks like a syntax error since `-d` only takes one argument.

Comment: I need two arguments, because comparing (finding files with same file) will be done in two different folders.

Comment: I edited as this; if [ ! -d "${folder1}" ] && [ ! -d "${folder2}" ]; then However I take same results.

Comment: perhaps if you change the line "find $dir2 -name $i -print" in your for loop to: find $dir -name $(basename $i) -print

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor My goal is finding files with same name in two different folders.

Comment: @user2874061 but are the folders more than one level deep? For example, do you want to find a match if you have `~/folder1/foo/bar.xyz` and `~/folder2/bah/bleh/bar.xyz`? Or are there *no* subfolders under `folder1` and `folder2`?

Comment: @Cillier The only change is that the results are printed as this: ./.mozilla ./.mozilla/extensions ...

Comment: oh, you probably also want to add "-type f" to both of the find commands

Comment: @mbratch No, the folders are only one level step. I want to find ~/folder1/abc and  ~/folder2/abc.

Comment: @mbratch There are not subfolders under folder1 and folder2.

Comment: I must have a fault my search script.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not traversing a tree but just looking into those folders specifically, you don't need find:

```
check_input_directories()
{
    if [ -d "${folder1}" ] && [ -d "${folder2}" ] ; then
        for i in ~/${folder1}/* ; do
            if [ -f ~/${folder2}/${i##*/} ] ; then
                echo ${i##*/}
            fi
        done
    fi
}
```

Comment: @user2874061 That is incorrect. `-d folder1 folder2` is invalid syntax. If you want to check for more than one folder, you have to do them separately as I have shown. I used "&&" which is *and*.

Comment: @user2874061 I tested the latest edit of the script I posted and it worked for me.